# watchOS 2 working with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, watchkit, watchos-2, watchos

Has anyone gotten CocoaPods working with watchOS 2? I tried using ‘use_framework!’ with ‘platform :watchos, ‘2.0’ but it says "[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: Unsupported platform `watchos2`. Platform must be `:ios` or `:osx`.. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.”

I am on the latest version of CocoaPods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CocoaPods currently doesn't support watchos. There is a work in progress issue [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/3681) for adding support for it.

Answer (score 5):

CocoaPods released new version which is 0.38.0 and now supports watchOS 2.
http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.38/

According to the blog above, deployment target can be set to watchOS 2 in `Podspec`.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
# …
s.watchos.deployment_target = '2.0'
end
```

You can set target for watchOS 2 in `Podfile` with the version.
However, library has to set the deployment target **explicitly**, so you need to check whether it's supported for each library in `Podspec`.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of CocoaPods supports this.

If you just need to get a pod working on watchOS 2 (e.g. Parse), the you can simply use a Podfile such as this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do

end

target 'MyApp WatchKit App' do

end

target 'MyApp WatchKit Extension' do
    platform :watchos, '2.0'
    pod 'Parse', '~> 1.11'
end
```

If however, you need to use the pod in multiple targets of different platforms (e.g. iOS and watchOS 2), things are slightly tricker. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34552179/35690) for more information.