# Error when validating podspec

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ios9, xcode7, podspec

I've created a cocoapod and I am attempting to validate its podspec, but I get this error:

```
➜  MyProject git:(master) ✗ pod spec lint MyProject.podspec

 -> MyProject (1.0)
    - ERROR | Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - ERROR | [iOS] Swift support uses dynamic frameworks and is therefore only supported on iOS > 8.
    - NOTE  |  [BEROR]error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'watchos'
    - NOTE  | [watchOS]  error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'watchos'
```

I am using Xcode 7 beta, developing for ios9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocoaPods currently doesn't support watchOS. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898729/watchos-2-working-with-cocoapods) for more info regarding the topic

Answer (score 0):

Searching for "error generated" in verbose mode should help you track down the error.